# Initialize multiple JPanels using a Flow Layout (Homework)

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager, flowlayout

I am trying to create a JFrame with two JPanels inserted inside using FlowLayout. I have the frame being initialized in a separate file, but here is what I have being called

```
public class FlowInFlow extends JFrame
{
public FlowInFlow() {

    setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    JPanel panel1 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
    panel1.setBackground(Color.RED);

    JPanel panel2 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));
    panel2.setBackground(Color.BLUE);   

}
}
```

Edit: When I run this I just get a blank box, when I need the two boxes side to side

Comment: ... and the problems you're having are...?? You need to tell us, since we are terrible at reading minds, you know.

Comment: I am guessing you seen no 'red or blue' since the components have no size.  But hey, you tell us.  Set a colored border to them, to check the size. Also, what is your question?

Comment: A `JPanel`'s default preferred size is 0x0.  Try adding something to them first.

Comment: 1) Add @HovercraftFullOfEels if you intend to inform them of updates 2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: *"I need the two boxes side to side"*  Use a single row `GridLayout`.

Comment: Thanks @AndrewThompson I wasnt aware of the "@" feature
But it has to be flowlayout, so I'll try adding something to the boxes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I've already stated, the default preferred size of a `JPanel` is 0x0...

This means that when you add it to a layout like `FlowLayout`, the uses the preferred size, it will appear...well...it won't

[image]

```
public class TestFlowLayout {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestFlowLayout();
    }

    public TestFlowLayout() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JPanel master = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
                JPanel left = new JPanel();
                left.setBackground(Color.RED);
                left.add(new JLabel("Lefty"));

                JPanel right = new JPanel();
                right.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
                right.add(new JLabel("Righty"));

                master.add(left);
                master.add(right);

                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(master);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Good example.  ..What is it with you and setting the PLAF?  I can't understand why you'd spend 7 LOC on such trivial matters!  (I suspect that without setting the PLAF, that example would show with no vertical scroll-bar.)

Comment: Thanks, This is just what I needed (using only FlowLayout). Except instead of left and right I will be initializing buttons. Thanks again

Comment: @AndrewThompson Netbeans macro, builds just about the whole code in the constructor :P

Comment: @AndrewThompson Bring on Java 7 I say ;)

Answer (score 4):

Besides the advice to change the outer layout, those components were never being added to anything (so would never be visible).

[image: Red/Blue Flow In Grid]

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class FlowInGrid extends JFrame  {

    public FlowInGrid() {

        setLayout(new GridLayout(1,0));

        JPanel panel1 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
        panel1.setBackground(Color.RED);
        // ADD Them to something!
        add(panel1);

        JPanel panel2 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));
        panel2.setBackground(Color.BLUE);   
        // ADD Them to something!
        add(panel2);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame f = new FlowInGrid();
                f.setSize(300,100);
                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the example but for this project I need to use flowlayout and not grid. The rest of your information was very helpful! Thanks again